# Wordpress problem after i updated file my theme to its latest version

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I'm getting this weird message when i try updating my theme to its latest version.

> Warning:
> require_once(/home/5/m/marysol/www/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/load.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/5/m/marysol/www/wp-content/themes/realhomes/functions.php on
> line 361
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> '/home/5/m/marysol/www/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/load.php'
> (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
> /home/5/m/marysol/www/wp-content/themes/realhomes/functions.php on
> line 361 There has been a critical error on this website. Please check
> your site admin email inbox for instructions.
>
> Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

And i can't access my website now. I can't access my dashboard too. What can be done? Need help.

Thank you.

Update: I've accessed files using FileZilla and i reverted my theme update change. Can you please suggest how can i update it?

Comment: Check this file themes/realhomes/functions.php on line 361 and fix your error or share to look into it.  Or just contact your theme dev to give you the best solution ,

Comment: `/**
 * Load functions files
 */
Line 361: require_once( INSPIRY_FRAMEWORK . 'functions/load.php' );

/**
 * Google Fonts
 */
require_once( INSPIRY_FRAMEWORK . 'customizer/google-fonts/google-fonts.php' );

/**`

This is what Line  361 says.

Comment: Well needs those files to load so check if they are there or contact your theme dev for best advice.